# There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: asp.net

I have a site www.pakcarid.com it shows this error when I browse 2 or 3 pages
where as the same server I have another site www.abc.pakcarid.com its run smooth.
Please tell me how to solve this issue.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: There is not enough space on the disk.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" Theme="SkinFile" MasterPageFile="MasterPage2.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" Title="pakcarid.com  ::  Sell and Buy car In Pakistan" %>
>
> Line 2:  <%@ Register TagPrefix="onlineofline" TagName="Link"  Src="~/OnlineOfline.ascx" %>
>
> Line 3:  <%@ Register TagName="model" TagPrefix="link" Src="~/make_model_status.ascx" %>

Comment: But do you have enough space on the server's harddisk(s)?

Comment: yes my auther site
www.abc.pakcarid.com 
in the same server

Comment: The fact that the other site works doesn't guarantee that the other site will work as well. You should check if the server's harddisks are not full.

Comment: Your main site says "Sing up" instead of "Sign up". Made me smile but you might want to fix your typo :)